# PHP pregmatch textarea

Tags: php, regex

Ok,so I have this form that contains textareas and I want to verify they dont contain any illegal characters.
Html:

```
<textarea minlength="100" required name="Description" maxlength="800">
</textarea>
```

Php:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[-\p{L}\p{N} #&()!*,.;'\/\\\\]+$/u",$_POST["Description"])){
 //error
}
```

I have tried multiple completely legal texts but it returns false.
What am I missing?

Comment: Place the `^` inside the square brackets. If you match like this it will search for one of those characters at the start of your string!

Comment: P.S.: use regex101.com to debug your regexes! It's awesome! :)

Comment: This was a really silly mistake on my part.I forgot to add \n and \r so that it checks for new lines.It is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your expression works fine, you might want to remove the `u` flag:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[-\p{L}\p{N} #&()!*,.;'\/\\\\]+$/s",$_POST["Description"])){
 //error
}
```

Or, you might be trying to do,

```
if(!preg_match("/^[^-\p{L}\p{N} #&()!*,.;'\/\\\\]+$/s",$_POST["Description"])){
 //error
}
```

if you want to exclude things out.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Vz6POS/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/^[-\p{L}\p{N} #&()!*,.;\'\/\\\\]+$/m';
$str = 'abcd
abcd\\\\\\\\\\\\
&*&??
abc?
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "abcd"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "abcd\\\\\\"
  }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mnRSdJ/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/mnRSdJ/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: I guess the intention was a completely different one. See my comment above!